# Removing Messages after Processing Azure Storeage Queues with Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-function-app, azure-storage-queues

I am a bit confused as to if I should be removing messages explicity after my Azure Function has processed the message.

I have an Azure Function that is triggerd when a new message is put on to Azure Storeage Queue. When my code has finished processing the message, do I need to explicity remove it from the queue?

Or is the fact that, the code has run without any errors, mean that the message will be removed from the queue automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you don't need to delete the message explicitly, the function will complete the message automatically if it succeeds. If the function throw an excepcion the message will go back to the queue with the DequeueCount property increased by one up to the limit that you configured in the host.josn(5 for default).

You can see all the properties here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-trigger?tabs=csharp-script#configuration